# Change location of breadcrumb in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image]How to Change the location of breadcrumb in Magento 2?

Which files create and how to do?

Comment: Where do you want to show it?

Comment: home page and also product page on top

Comment: I am curious why breadcrump is needed on Home page. and in product page it already shows on the top. You can use `<move>` node in layout files to show it at a different location on any page. Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251280/magento-2-how-to-move-breadcrumbs-and-sku-before-product-title

Comment: ok right but which location I am add this move node and change different location In my theme no any files created so how to do?

Comment: For product page, you can create following xml file in your custom theme `app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`. Change `Vendor_name/theme_name` according to your theme name.

Comment: yes ple see pic home->addidas->.....this is move right side how to do? and catalog_product_view.xml file ple send me

Comment: You can move it towards right side on the same line with the help of css code itself. No need to create layout file in this case. Do you have a custom theme?

Comment: yes I have create a custom theme and no any catalog_product_view.xml file in my theme ..and also how to change in css ?

Comment: You can follow this to modify css https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html